# Opposite of __set_state() like __get_state()?

Tags: php, class, object

Is there an opposite PHP function for `__set_state()` like `__get_state()`? And I don't mean `__sleep()` for serialization. I want a simple function which is called after `var_export()` is called on a object but before `var_export()` gets the data so I can choose on each object which data will be exported. <del>I know there is a way to implement this with `__get()` and `debug_backtrace()` to modify the data only when `var_export()` is called on a object.</del> But is there a simpler way?

**Edit**: There is no way to implement this with `__get()` and `debug_backtrace()` to modify the data only when `var_export()` is called on a object because `__get()` is not called on `var_export()`.

**Solution**:

```
<?php
/*
 * @author Christian Mayer <http://fox21.at>
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/21762276/823644
 * @link https://eval.in/163041
 * @link https://eval.in/163462
 * @link https://eval.in/163909
 * @link https://gist.github.com/TheFox/49ff6903da287c30e72f
 */

interface Exportable{
    public function __get_state();
}

function unset_with_get_state($expression){
    $before = clone $expression;
    $classVars = array_keys(get_class_vars(get_class($before)));
    foreach(array_diff($classVars, $before->__get_state()) as $var){
        unset($before->$var);
    }
    return $before;
}

function my_var_export($expression, $return = null){
    $before = $expression;
    if($before instanceof Exportable){
        $before = unset_with_get_state($expression);
    }
    return var_export($before, $return);
}

class Foo implements Exportable{
    public $name = null;
    public $foo = null;
    public $bar = null;

    public function __get_state(){
        // Only show 'name' and 'bar' on my_var_export().
        return array('name', 'bar');
    }
}

$a = 'hello';
my_var_export($a);
print "\n";

$b = new Foo();
$b->name = 'world';
$b->foo = 'foo is foo';
$b->bar = 'bar is bar';
my_var_export($b);
print "\n";
```

Of course with an own implementation you can do everything. With `is there a simpler way?` I mean if there is a built-in PHP function or something like that so you don't have to do it yourself. This solution is not really *easy* because you must extend all your objects from `Exportable`. And this also only works when your variables are `public`. In this example I choosed to export only `name` and `bar` but not `foo`. A built-in PHP function (like `__set_state()` is) would be more nicer.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do this. What are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to store an object that can later be `eval`'d, that seems like a dubious use for this. Why not create an "export" method to do this?

Comment: I want that debugging is simpler. When you have an object with circular references you can't debug these objects in a handsome way. It's not logically that there is no opposite to `__set_state()`. The PHP documentation says: `This static method is called for classes exported by var_export() [...]`. But if you export some variables you probably want to import them. So I want a function like `__sleep()` where I can choose the object variables which will be exported and shown when I call `var_export()` on a object.

Comment: var_export() will export all your properties and you can't choose which props you want. There's no such magic method for that. If you really want to do this, you have to do what @Brian said: "create an 'export' method to do this".

Answer (score 8):

You write in your question:

> I want a simple function which is called after var_export() is called on a object but before var_export() gets the data

That sounds like that you want to adopt the `var_export()` function and then call the adapter instead of `var_export()`. Then inside the adapter you would get the data *before* it is (really) *`var_export()ed`*:

```
function my_var_export($expression, $return = NULL) {
    $before = $expression;
    return var_export($before, $return);
}

$a = 'hello';
my_var_export($a); // 'hello'
```

With this adapter, you're technically able then to establish what you're looking for, but it is also the precondition.

So we're concerned about objects, not strings. And for those objects, the `__get_state()` method should be called. As we so far know what such an object should be (it should be *exportable*), we create an interface:

```
interface Exportable {
    /**
     * @return static clone of $this for var_export
     */
    public function __get_state();
}
```

So how could this be implemented? One idea is to clone the real object and then change it so that `var_export` does not run into any problems with it. This cloning will spare us to manipulate the concrete object just to export it. But this is only a convention, an object which can't be cloned could implement this `__get_state()` method as well, it would be perhaps just a little more complicated to write the implementation then.

And on the other end, with the help of the interface, the adaptor `my_var_export()` can be made more intelligent on how to treat `$before` on passing it to `var_export()`:

```
function my_var_export($expression, $return = null)
{
    $before = $expression instanceof Exportable
        ? $expression->__get_state()
        : $expression;

    return var_export($before, $return);
}
```

Just the new case that an *Exportable* `$expression` needs special treatment has been inserted. This works just as before for the `$a = 'hello';` expression.

So now to give it a go, we need a concrete type that is an *Exportable*, exemplary I use a **Foo** here. For testing purposes I give it a private property that is only set in case the implementation of `__get_state()` has been called in the adopted `var_export()` operation:

```
class Foo implements Exportable
{
    private $name = null;
    private $__get_state_called;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string)$name;
    }

    public function __get_state()
    {
        $before = clone $this; // or if inherited: parent::__get_state()

        $before->__get_state_called = true;

        return $before;
    }
}
```

The working example than is:

```
$b = new Foo('hello');
my_var_export($b);
```

Which gives the output as wanted:

```
Foo::__set_state(array(
   'name' => 'hello',
   '__get_state_called' => true,
))
```

And that's your "magic" function `__get_state()` that is called *before* `var_export()`  gets the data but *after* (`my_`)`var_export()` is called.

Adapt the function `var_export` to add the functionality you need. Use an interface for the objects that need special treatment.

The full example ([run it online](https://eval.in/163041)):

```
<?php
/*
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wrodpress.com/>
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/24228153/367456
 * @link https://eval.in/163041
 */

/**
 * Interface Exportable
 */
interface Exportable
{
    /**
     * @return static clone of $this for var_export
     */
    public function __get_state();
}

/**
 * @param mixed $expression
 * @param bool  $return (optional)
 *
 * @return void|string
 */
function my_var_export($expression, $return = null)
{
    $before = $expression instanceof Exportable
        ? $expression->__get_state()
        : $expression;

    return var_export($before, $return);
}

/**
 * Class Foo
 */
class Foo implements Exportable
{
    private $name = null;
    private $__get_state_called;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string)$name;
    }

    /**
     * @see Exportable
     * @return Foo|static
     */
    public function __get_state()
    {
        $before = clone $this; // or if inherited: parent::__get_state()

        $before->__get_state_called = true;

        return $before;
    }
}

$a = 'hello';
my_var_export($a);

echo "\n\n";

$b = new Foo('world');
my_var_export($b);
```

Comment: Congrats! You almost have **100K** and +1

Comment: On your first quote of my question you forgot `so I can choose on each object which data will be exported`. Of course with an own adoption you can do everything. With `is there a simpler way?` I mean if there is a built-in PHP function or something like that so you don't have to do it yourself. This solution is not really *easy* because you must extend all your objects from `Exportable`. I come to this solution: https://eval.in/163462. A built-in PHP function (like `__set_state()` is) would be more nicer. However thanks for your solution.

Comment: And by the way I think you typed "wordpress.com" wrong in your example codes.

Comment: @TheFox: You don't need to *extend* from `Exportable` but just *implement* it. That's a little different (but however, you have some work with it, yes, you can look into Reflection in case it helps to move code from the objects themselves into a helper method). And right, I typed it wrong ;) I think I collect some changes and the polish it. And if there would have been something built in, I would have named it. I'm pretty sure there is no such thing, you would need to figure out some PHP extension that adds this but I'm not sure this is worthy as pretty specialized.